# using postgres server-side cursor for caching

Tags: postgresql

To speed page generation for pages based on large postgres collections, we cache query results in memcache. However, for immutable collections that are very large, or that are rarely accessed, I'm wondering if saving server side cursors in postgres would be a viable alternate caching strategy.

The idea is that after having served a page in the middle of a collection "next" and "prev" links are much more likely to be used than a random query somewhere else in the collection. Could I have a cursor "WITH HOLD" in the neighborhood to avoid the (seemingly unavoidable) large startup costs of the query?

I wonder about resource consumption on the server. If the collection is immutable, saving the cursor shouldn't need very many resources, but I wonder how optimized postgres is in this respect. Any links to further documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: The caching strategy I envision would be to store a fixed number of cursors. If one is near by for a particular query, it would be used to retrieve a page of results. Otherwise the cursor which has sat unused for the longest would be reset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to run into a lot of issues.

- You 'd have to ensure the same user gets the same sql connection
- You have to create a cleanup strategy
- The cursors will be holding up vacuum operations.
- You have to convince the connection pool to not clear the cursors
- Probably other issues I have not mentioned.

In short: don't do it. How about precalculating the next/previous page in background, and storing it in memcached?

Comment: hmm-- can you point me to where in the doc it discusses the relation between cursors and connections? Without "with hold" the cursor is only valid in the transaction, but I can find no mention of the dependence of the cursor on the transaction in: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-declare.html

Comment: UPDATE: "can continue to be accessed by subsequent transactions *in the same session* " -- sigh... precalc still duplicates scan, but I guess > (last PK -- or whatever the query was sorted on) would avoid this. ok

Answer (score 3):

A good answer to this has previously been made [Best way to fetch the continuous list with PostgreSQL in web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746920/best-way-to-fetch-the-continuous-list-with-postgresql-in-web)

The questions are similar, essentially you store a list of PKs on the server with a pagination-token and an expiration.